# Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have this error

> "Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable"

in this code

```
private async void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var frenchvoice = InstalledVoices.All.Where(voice => voice.Language.Equals("fr-FR") & voice.Gender == VoiceGender.Female).FirstOrDefault; // in this line
    sp.SetVoice(frenchvoice);
    await sp.SpeakTextAsync(mytxt);
}
```

Answer (score 76):

You forgot to call the function (with `()`)

Answer (score 25):

You must add the round brackets to call the method `FirstOrDefault`

```
   var frenchvoice = InstalledVoices.All
       .Where(voice => voice.Language.Equals("fr-FR") && 
                       voice.Gender == VoiceGender.Female)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

And, while your code works also using the & operator, the correct one to use in a logical condition  is `&&`

By the way, `FirstOrDefault` accepts the same lambda applied to Where so you could reduce your code to a simpler and probably faster

```
   var frenchvoice = InstalledVoices.All
       .FirstOrDefault(voice => voice.Language.Equals("fr-FR") && 
                                voice.Gender == VoiceGender.Female);
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I hit this problem converting VB to C#. Should be marked as best answer IMO.