# How to assign ObjectResult<> from EF

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, dbcontext

After using DB first approach with EF my context.cs file has the follwing for a stored procedure:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<selectCases_Result> selectCases()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<selectCases_Result>("selectPurgeCaseFolio");
}
```

In a sepearte class file I'm trying to invoke it to get the result with the following:

```
public SelectCases()
{    
  var result = _context.selectCases;
}
```

However the error I get is on result:

> "Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable"

How can I get the result of this select query into a dataset or anyother type of object to see the results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623299/cannot-assign-method-group-to-an-implicitly-typed-local-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call the method (with ())

```
var result = _context.selectCases();
```

You are trying to call it like a property when you should be calling it as a method